# How to pass event into lamda function

Tags: javascript, events

When I create an eventlistener I can't figure out how to pass the event into the function called.

```
class Clickable
{
    constructor()
    {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => this.action());
    }

    action(mouseEvent)
    {
        console.log(mouseEvent); //Undefined
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the `event` from the `mousedown` listener to the function like this:

```
class Clickable {
    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.action(e));
    }
    action(mouseEvent) {
        console.log(mouseEvent);
    }
}
```